# Is there a way to intercept all method calls in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I need to intercept method calls on predefined Java classes. For example, lets say I need to intercept String class split method, how do I do this?

I tried [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3515-Interception) which works, but I doesn’t want end user to change their code by wrapping their calls in with proxy block.

Is there any way this can be achieved with Groovy?

Answer (score 4):

If what you want to do is intercept a call to a specific method you can do something like this...

```
// intercept calls to the split method on java.lang.String
String.metaClass.split = { String arg ->
    // do whatever you want to do
}
```

If what you want to do is intercept a call to a specific method and do some stuff in addition to invoking the original (like to wrap the real method with some of your own logic) you can do something like this:

```
// get a reference to the original method...
def originalSplit = String.metaClass.getMetaMethod('split', [String] as Class[])

// now add your own version of the method to the meta class...
String.metaClass.split = { String arg ->
    // do something before invoking the original...

    // invoke the original...
    def result = originalSplit.invoke(delegate, arg)

    // do something after invoking the original...

    // return the result of invoking the original
    result
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Note that all of that is only going to apply to calls to the `split` method from Groovy.  You are not going to be able to intercept calls to the `split` method that come from Java or any other language.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `MetaClass` for that [see doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses)

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
//call 'enableGlobally' method before adding to supplied class
String.metaClass.split = { regex -> 
  println "calling split from $delegate with $regex"
  delegate.split regex, 22
}
```

Comment: What is the "22" for?

Comment: should have written 42 :)

Answer (score 0):

To intercept all method calls in a class override Groovy's [`invokeMethod`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_invokemethod). Example:

```
class Test {}
 
Test.metaClass.foo = {"foo() called"}
Test.metaClass.static.bar = {"bar() called"}

Test.metaClass.invokeMethod = { name, args ->
    handleInterception(name, args, delegate, false)
}

Test.metaClass.static.invokeMethod = { name, args ->
    handleInterception(name, args, delegate, true)
}
 
def handleInterception(name, args, delegate, isStatic) {
    def effDelegate = isStatic ? delegate : delegate.class
    
    println ">> Entering ${delegate.class.name}.$name() with args: $args"
    
    def metaMethod = effDelegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    if (!metaMethod) {
        println "-- Method not found: $name($args)"
        return
    }
 
    try {
        def result = metaMethod.invoke(delegate, args)
        println "<< Leaving ${delegate.class.name}.$name() with result: $result"
        return result
    } catch (ex) {
        println "-- Exception occurred in $name: $ex.message"
        throw ex
    }
}
 
new Test().foo("1", 2)
Test.bar(2)
new Test().onTheFly(3)
```

Code taken from [Roshan Dawrani's post](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/363001) at groovyconsole.appspot.com.

Output:

```
>> Entering Test.foo() with args: [1, 2]
-- Method not found: foo([1, 2])
>> Entering java.lang.Class.bar() with args: [2]
<< Leaving java.lang.Class.bar() with result: bar() called
>> Entering Test.onTheFly() with args: [3]
-- Method not found: onTheFly([3])
```

Other options:

- [Custom MetaClass](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_custom_metaclasses) implementing invokeMethod
- Implementing the [Interceptor](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Interceptor.html) Interface. Read more in [this tutorial](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-intercept-methods-with.html)